# Can a straight line boundary transform into a pair of straight lines?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, transformation

Consider the region $D$ bounded by the straight lines $x=0$, $y=0$, and $x+y=1$. Clearly, the region is a triangle in the first quadrant. I want to transform this region using the transformation $x=u(1-v)$ and $y=uv$ for the purpose of evaluating a double integral.

As we can see,

$x=0 \implies u=0, v=1$

$y=0 \implies u=0, v=0$

$x+y=1 \implies u=1$

Does this mean that the straight line boundary $x=0$ transformed into a pair of straight lines ($u=0$ and $v=1$) on the $uv$ plane?
[image]

Comment: @AnneBauval No the transformation was from $(x,y)$ to $(u,v)$. I rewrote the equations so that you don't have to calculate it. The original equations were $x+y=u$ and $y=uv$.

Comment: @AnneBauval I understand that. I've written the original equation in the above comment. Now, if you could help me with the real proble, that would be great.

Comment: @Are you telling me that the transformation $x+y=u$ and $y=uv$ is not a map from $xy$ to the $uv$ plane?

Comment: @AnneBauval I'm no expert but this is a question from my textbook. I've attached the image of the question now for your reference. So is the question wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transformation is not a map $(x,y)\mapsto(u,v).$ It is a map $(u,v)\mapsto(x,y).$ So, your question makes little sense.

Even when written $x+y=u,y=uv,$ the transformation is not a map from the  $xy$ to the $uv$ plane. It is undefined on the straight line $x=0$ you are interested in.

The only thing we can say is that your *open* triangle is transformed into the open square $(0,1)^2,$ because
$$\begin{align}(u(1-v)>0\land uv>0\land u<1)&\iff\\(v(1-v)>0\land uv>0\land u<1)&\iff\\0<v<1\land0<u<1.
\end{align}$$
This proves the last line of the solution in your attached image.

Comment: Okay. It would be great if you could also explain what is wrong with the question in the attached image.

Comment: I can see no question in the attached image. What is wrong imo (or rather nonsense) is *your* question. And also, the line in your image before the last one, which you reproduced identically in your post, is anyway useless (or at least not sufficient to prove the last line) but not well written: some periods should be replaced by "or". E.g. $u=0,v=1$ should be replaced by $u=0$ *or* $v=1.$

Comment: Okay, I didn't realize that by 'transformation' or 'map' you meant a function. I understand that for the point $(0,0)$ in the $xy$ plane, there is no unique image in $uv$, which means, it is not a function, but clearly the relation is a function from $uv$ to the $xy$ plane. So far so good.

But does it matter whether the relation is a function or not as far as the evaluation of the integral is concerned?

Can I say the map transforms a pair of straight lines ($u=0$ and $v=1$) in the $uv$ plane to a straight line $x=0$ in the $xy$ plane?

Comment: Yes, as commented from the beginning, it is a [transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_(function)), or [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(mathematics)) $(u,v)\mapsto(x,y)$ and not $(x,y)\mapsto(u,v).$ And it does matter for the (non-)sense of your main question, but it doesn't matter indeed for the evaluation of the integral, since it restricts to a true bijection between the open triangle and the open square.

Comment: Okay, since it is a function from $(u,v)$ to $(x,y)$, can I say the map transforms a pair of straight lines ($u=0$ and $v=1$) in the $uv$ plane to the straight line $x=0$ in the $xy$ plane?

Comment: The line $u=0$ is mapped to the point $(x,y)=(0,0).$ The line $v=1$ is mapped to the line $x=0.$

Comment: Okay, got it. So if I'm right, this is how I should find the limits of $u$ and $v$:

$x>0 \implies u(1-v)>0 \implies u>0$ and $v<1$.
$y>0 \implies uv>0 \implies u>0$ and $v>0$.
$x+y<1 \implies u<1$.

From this it is clear that both $u$ and $v$ vary from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Your proof is not correct. A product $>0$ only implies both factors are $>0$ *or both are $<0.$* A correct proof  is in my answer.

Comment: Oh, right. Your proof was a bit terse for me to grasp, but I think this is the essence of it:

$u-uv>0 \implies u>uv$. But $uv>0 \implies u>0 \implies v>0$. Also, $u>0 \implies v<1$, as $u(1-v)>0$.

Comment: I got that. But since $u>uv$ and $uv>0$ that implies $u>0$.

Comment: Oh, ok! But my proof was different: I used $uv>0$ to deduce that $u$ has the same sign as $v$ hence can be replaced by $v$ in the first condition $u(1-v)>0.$ Then, $v(1-v)>0\iff 0<v<1$, and $(0<v\land uv>0)\iff(0<v\land u>0).$